# Is it possible to simulate Big Data flow on Mongo DB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, heroku

I’ve thought about making a server with routes/models that will be hosted on Heroku so that it can process requests.  Then I would make incremental requests to the server until they can be qualified as Big Data.
I think that there is limitation to how many consequtive requests one pc can make to a mongo datbase, although I couldn’t find any prove on that. 
I need results of Big Data flow so that I could further analyze and include them in my essay.

Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: "If your data fits on a USB stick, it's not big data". You can get 2TB sticks these days.

Comment: "there is limitation to how many consequtive requests one pc can make to a mongo datbase" - no such limit. You can send as many requests as your hardware can tolerate.

Comment: Then the question is could a PC generate data bigger than 2TB with HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMeter, JMeter  is a Load testing is the process of putting the load through (HTTP, HTTPS, WebSocket etc) calls on any software system to determine its behavior under normal and high load conditions. Load test helps identify maximum requests a software system can handle.